# Resize dojox chart on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, arcgis-js-api, dojox.charting

I am using this [Info window with chart](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_infowindowchart.html) ESRI tutorial.

[image]

And I would like to customize the dojox pie chart for smaller screens:

```
@media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    ...
  }
```

Is it possible to use custom dojox chart sizes for custom screen sizes ?

For example the pie chart to be {width: 60px; height: 60px} only when loading on a screen with max-device-width: 320px ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.

[image]

However I am afraid that you can not achieve this only by CSS, Because the size of chart depends on various factors. like `chart radius`, `map infoWindow size`, `container size` etc.

**Solution-** 
You can change above values based on the screen size dynamically, you can use `window resize event` for it.. this is how you can achieve this.

**Below is the working code-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Info Window with Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .chart {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        padding:0px !important;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      // Try other themes: Julie, CubanShirts, PrimaryColors, Charged, BlueDusk, Bahamation, Harmony, Shrooms
      var theme = "Wetland";
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/dijit/InfoWindow", "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dojox/charting/Chart2D", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
        "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight", "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
        "dojox/charting/themes/" + theme,
        "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom-class",
        "dojo/number", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        InfoWindow, InfoTemplate,
        SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer,
        ContentPane, TabContainer,
        Chart2D, Pie,
        Highlight, MoveSlice, Tooltip,
        dojoxTheme,
        domConstruct, domClass,
        number, parser
      ) {
        // Use the info window instead of the popup.
        var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(null, domConstruct.create("div"));
        infoWindow.startup();

        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-113.405, 43.521],
          infoWindow: infoWindow,
          zoom: 6
        });
        map.infoWindow.resize(180, 200);

        var template = new esri.InfoTemplate();
        // Flag icons are from http://twitter.com/thefella, released under creative commons.
        template.setTitle("<b><img src='flags/${STATE_ABBR}.png'>  ${STATE_NAME}</b>");
        template.setContent(getWindowContent);

        var statesLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
          infoTemplate: template,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        statesLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));

        map.addLayer(statesLayer);

        function getWindowContent(graphic) {
          // Make a tab container.
          var tc = new TabContainer({
            style: "width:100%;height:100%;"
          }, domConstruct.create("div"));

          // Display attribute information.
          var cp1 = new ContentPane({
            title: "Details",
            content: "<a target='_blank' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" +
              graphic.attributes.STATE_NAME + "'>Wikipedia Entry</a><br><br>Median Age: " +
              graphic.attributes.MED_AGE + "<br>Median Age (Male): " +
              graphic.attributes.MED_AGE_M + "<br>Median Age (Female): " +
              graphic.attributes.MED_AGE_F
          });
          // Display a dojo pie chart for the male/female percentage.
          var cp2 = new ContentPane({
            title: "Pie Chart"
          });
          tc.addChild(cp1);
          tc.addChild(cp2);

          // Create the chart that will display in the second tab.
          var c = domConstruct.create("div", {
            id: "demoChart"
          }, domConstruct.create("div"));
          var chart = new Chart2D(c);
          domClass.add(chart, "chart");

          // Apply a color theme to the chart.
          chart.setTheme(dojoxTheme);
          chart.addPlot("default", {
            type: "Pie",
            radius: 45,
            htmlLabels: true
          });
          tc.watch("selectedChildWidget", function(name, oldVal, newVal){
            if ( newVal.title === "Pie Chart" ) {
              chart.resize(100,100);
            }
          });

          // Calculate percent male/female.
          var total = graphic.attributes.POP2000;
          var male = number.round(graphic.attributes.MALES / total * 100, 2);
          var female = number.round(graphic.attributes.FEMALES / total * 100, 2);
          chart.addSeries("PopulationSplit", [{
            y: male,
            tooltip: male,
            text: "Male"
          }, {
            y: female,
            tooltip: female,
            text: "Female"
          }]);
          //highlight the chart and display tooltips when you mouse over a slice.
          new Highlight(chart, "default");
          new Tooltip(chart, "default");
          new MoveSlice(chart, "default");

          cp2.set("content", chart.node);
          return tc.domNode;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Hi @Developerrrr Thank you! Changing the values inside the script will target all screens loading the web app. So basically you can not customize dojox charts just for small mobile screens and keep their initial size for larger screens. Just trying to understand how this works... is my assessment correct ?

Comment: your point is correct. I am suggesting to change those values based on screen size. use JavaScript code for this instead of  CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onresize   --- this sample shows how can you check the width/height of the device or browser... so basically you have to add an "onresize" on your code and call a function that faction will change those values based on screen size...

Comment: It's not straight forward to implement, I am just suggesting you how can you achieve this.. an alternative way to do this... If its that important in your project you can use this alternative way...